# Strategy Pattern - Input from UI

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface

I have a very simple question. I have a User interface which prompts the user to choose "Option A" or "Option B" (Actual option buttons). Once the user chooses I call in to a repository that connects to a database to get some data.

Option A would require a certain type of query and Option B would generate different. Without getting to specifics, I have implemented a strategy pattern called OptionAStrategy and OptionBStrategy that would generate the correct query so that repository can use the query.

Now the question is how do I pass the fact that user choose "Option A" or B. I can pass the actual string say "Option A" or "Option B" and pass that string to a StrategyFactory to instantiate the correct OptionStartegy. But is that a good practice else

#### How does the UI communicate a chosen UI option so that a strategy factory can correctly instantiate the correct instance of strategy? assuming strategy sits at repositories level

Thanks in Advance
Cheers

Bump: No answers - low views :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your strategies as implementations of an [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) or `ActionListener` and then attach them to a specific UI element, such as a [`JButton`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#JButton%28javax.swing.Action%29). Upon user click, that action would be executed.
For example, using Java Swing:

```
final Action optionA = new AbstractAction("Option A") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // option A code
    }
};
final JButton optionAButton = new JButton(optionA);
// add button to UI
```

- [*How to Use Actions*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)
- [`AbstractAction`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html)

A benefit of using Swing actions is that many of the UI components can be constructed from an `Action`, allowing you to provide multiple UI mechanisms of varying style that all perform the same function.

The next step would be to create factories for providing these different `Action`s to some sort of application-specific controller that would then inject them into the UI components.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have context and Strategy interface. In your context you can choose you if/else to choose the appropriate strategy or use factory class to get you startegy. See it [Here](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html).